# Accessing files on SD Card from WP7 application

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any way to access the any type of file (Image/text/Media) on SD card from Windows Phone 7 application. 
I have read from the multiple articles that WP7 applications can access only those files which are available under an application's IsolatedStorageFile (Which is local to an application).
Does anyone knows a way to read the file directly from the SD card on the phone or the SD card file could be moved/write to an application's IsolatedStorageFile.

Comment: have you found the answer to read from Phone internal storage ?

Answer (score 3):

Current version of Windows Phone 7 doesn't support SD cards.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I think i need to elaborate the scenario.
I have been writting the Image Upload API for WP7.
That means there is a need to read the file from the Windows Phone storage (not necessarily SD card).
I have successfully implemented it for Android and its working fine.
But in WP7 implementation, I have read at many places that Windows Phone applications run in a sandboxed process which
means that the files can not be accessed outside the app.
Is there any way to access/read the file from the Phone Storage?

Comment: Yes, that is right your application is sandboxed and the only access to the external files you have is phone images. What are the files you are trying to read? Post it as a separate question.

Comment: Hi Vitalij. Is there any way that we can create a file from one application and allow other applications to access that file. What I baiscally meant by that is, if we can save the file only in application's isolated storage, then any other application won't be able to access it. For example a scenario like this. One application produce a file and later the email client application need that file to send as an attachment. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone 8, you can access files under the device SD Card using Microsoft.Phone.Storage API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj720573(v=vs.105).aspx